# JOIN by a number of criterias

Tags: mysql, join

I have got this sql:

```
SELECT 
     artists.id, 
     actors.id, 
     actors.count 
FROM 
     artists 
INNER JOIN actors ON artists.title = actors.title;
```

Actors table have got duplications and some `counter` field. So there can be

```
Tom Waits | 10
Tom Waits | 30
```

How can I change my first sql so it will return only those actors, who have got `MAX(count)`

Something like

```
SELECT 
     artists.id, 
     actors.id, 
     actors.count 
FROM 
     artists 
INNER JOIN actors ON artists.title = actors.title 
HAVING MAX(actors.count);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT  actors.id
        , MAX(actors.count)
FROM    artists 
        INNER JOIN actors ON artists.title = actors.title
GROUP BY
        actors.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one -

```
SELECT artists.id, actors.id, actors.`count` FROM artists
  INNER JOIN actors
    ON artists.title = actors.title
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT title, MAX(`count`) max_count FROM actors
      GROUP BY title
    ) actors2
    ON actors.title = actors2.title AND actors.`count` = actors2.max_count;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT artists.id, a.id, a.count 
FROM artists 
INNER JOIN ( SELECT actors.id, actors.count 
             FROM actors
             HAVING MAX(actors.count) ) a ON artists.title = a.title
```

Answer (score 0):

The easy way:

```
SELECT 
  artists.id, 
  (select actors.id 
   from actors 
   where artists.title = actors.title 
   order by actors.count desc Limit 1) 
  as actors_id,
  (select actors.count 
   from actors 
   where artists.title = actors.title 
   order by actors.count desc Limit 1) 
  as actors.count 
FROM 
  artists 
;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT 
     artists.id, 
     actors.id, 
     MAX(actors.count) 
FROM 
     artists 
INNER JOIN actors ON artists.title = actors.title;
GROUP BY
    actors.id
```

Comment: some GROUP BY condition missing here.